# Androids bluetooth connection with accessory keeps dropping

Tags: bluetooth, motorola

I have an accessory that connects with smartphone through dedicated app.

I tested it on few other phones and tablets - they work great.

Yet for some reason while connecting to my Moto E20 phone, the connection drops after ~5 sec. Then it reconnects after another 15, drops again, untill after few times fails completly.

I tried to test all different settings, with zero success. Made sure that there's no battery savings, no processes limit, changed Bluetooth from 1.4 to 1.6 etc. What could possibly cause that? I don't want to reset device to default :/

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Is the Bluetooth accessory also paired with other devices near you, thus the other device may be trying to connect to it, and the accessory disconnects the connection to the Moto E20? Or in other words, have you tried unpairing it from all devices and only pairing it to Moto E20?

Comment: To time it, how did you observe that it was dropping